# No OpenID endpoint found for DotNetOpenAuth ASP.NET MVC Login sample

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openid, dotnetopenauth

I am trying out `DotNetOpenAuth ASP.NET MVC Login sample`. I am able to log in using Google endpoint only. If I use anything else (like Blogger or Yahoo) I get `No OpenID endpoint found`. What could be the problem here?

I have tried logging errors as suggested [here](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/help/loggingdebugging-dotnetopenauth-with-log4net/) but this does not seem to work for a MVC sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to have been in the fact that `OpenIdRelyingParty.SecuritySettings.RequireSsl` has been explicitly set to `true`. After commenting this out, suddenly all other OpenID providers started working. It seems as if Google is the only one supporting SSL.

Comment: Yahoo! also supports HTTPS, but your identifier has to be `https://me.yahoo.com/`

Comment: Mine is set to false, still receiving this error. Very annoying how there are so many reasons for one error message.